# Http error 500 in WordPress website

Tags: wordpress

sparkleplasticsurgery.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

My website is on WordPress. I changed images and that time website working properly and after sometime suddenly this error occurs. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable Debug in WordPress in Config file by adding True

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

Then check what error message show in site. or you can also check error message in error_log file in root..

Please check then let me know what error message shown..